# RxJava mergeDelayError OnErrorFailedException Error: occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError

Tags: java, rx-java

When I use `mergeDelayError` on a list of observables to execute each observable before erroring out, I get:

```
OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
```

Code:

```
return Observable.mergeDelayError(Observable.from(observableList));
```

Where I subscribe to the observable with an argument for `onError` (which is also not executed).

However, when I tried use `onErrorResumeNext` to debug this, I found that propagating the observable error caused no issues. What is happening here?

```
return Observable.mergeDelayError(Observable.from(observableList)).onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Pair<String, Map<Long, Set<ProgressGradedItemBL>>>>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<? extends Pair<String, Map<Long, Set<ProgressGradedItemBL>>>> call(Throwable throwable) {
        return Observable.error(throwable);
    }
});
```

Here's the stacktrace I get without `onErrorResumeNext`:

```
rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:175)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:97)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.drainAndComplete(OperatorMerge.java:466)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.completeInner(OperatorMerge.java:449)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:599)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:542)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.drainAndComplete(OperatorMerge.java:472)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.completeInner(OperatorMerge.java:449)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:614)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:542)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeCombineLatest$MultiSourceProducer.tick(OnSubscribeCombineLatest.java:151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeCombineLatest$MultiSourceProducer.onCompleted(OnSubscribeCombineLatest.java:183)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeCombineLatest$MultiSourceRequestableSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeCombineLatest.java:236)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.drainAndComplete(OperatorMerge.java:472)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:435)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.drainAndComplete(OperatorMerge.java:472)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.completeInner(OperatorMerge.java:449)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:614)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:542)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.drainAndComplete(OperatorMerge.java:472)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:435)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.drainAndComplete(OperatorMerge.java:472)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.completeInner(OperatorMerge.java:449)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:614)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:542)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDistinctUntilChanged$1.onCompleted(OperatorDistinctUntilChanged.java:64)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onCompleted(OperatorDoOnEach.java:53)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorFilter$1.onCompleted(OperatorFilter.java:42)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onCompleted(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:66)
    at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onCompleted(SerializedObserver.java:99)
    at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onCompleted(SerializedSubscriber.java:46)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:158)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.completeInner(OperatorConcat.java:150)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatInnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorConcat.java:212)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onCompleted(OperatorDoOnEach.java:53)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onCompleted(OperatorDoOnEach.java:53)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onCompleted(OperatorDoOnEach.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OnErrorFailedException` is thrown when you use the `subscribe(Action1)` instead of `subscribe(Action1, Action1)`. In addition, you seem to use an older version of RxJava (the name `drainAndComplete` was like 1.0.12 and before). The current version is 1.1.2.

Comment: I am subscribing to the observable using ```subscribe(final Action1<? super T> onNext, final Action1<Throwable> onError``` so I don't believe that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if your stream throw an unchecked exception against the Observable then the observable processing is abort an throw an OnErrorFailedException.